# What's the best notation for "a set XOR a single element" for a journal?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-set-theory, notation

I am trying to publish in an area of mathematics (number theory) where I haven't encountered the XOR once -- neither in literature, nor in books.  For a proof, I have a set $S$, and I need to xor it with an element $x$.  The classical way to express such an xor is to say $$
T:= S\setminus\{x\}\cup(\{x\}\setminus S)$$ -- but, the latter half doesn't look very intuitive.  I can also say

```
Let T be S \ {x} if xєS, and S U {x} otherwise.
```

This seems more intuitive.  Is this the best way of saying it?  I'll accept the answer which gets more votes.

Comment: Not sure what you want to say but the latter is at least readable (and good style).

Comment: See ["symmetric difference"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference).

Comment: @Blue Sure, but my question was how to express this in a journal article.  If I use any of those circle notations, the readers won't know what I'm talking about because this is not a logic journal, but number theory.  And I don't want to introduce new notation if I'm gonna use it only one time in the whole paper.

Comment: @Alex: *"my question was how to express this in a journal article"* ... I don't see any mention of a journal article, or the focus of such a journal. You should explicitly state this context in the body of the question; please include name of the specific journal, as well. Someone may be aware of editorial guidelines about, or existing articles using, the kind of notation you seek.

Comment: @Blue Good point, I should have said something about it -- but I don't want to draw attention to a specific journal, because math language should be pretty standard within a given subject, regardless of which journal it is.  Do you think my current edit gives enough info?

Comment: @Alex: Well, at least now you mention "publishing", which is better. But if "math language should be pretty standard within a given subject", then you should probably identify the given subject. :)  Giving an example of how you'd use the notation in an argument would probably help, too. ... Withholding the journal name seems unwarranted —more information is better— but ... whatever.

Answer (score 2):

I would follow your more intuitive version, slightly improved by using the *cases* facility of $\LaTeX$.
Let $T$ be the set defined by
$$
T = \begin{cases}
S \setminus \{x\} &\text{if $x \in S$}\\
S \cup \{x\} &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Note that, as the definition depends on $S$ and $x$, you may wish to replace $T$ by $T(x)$ or by $T(S,x)$ if you are using this construction with different values of $S$ and $x$.

Comment: The multi-line presentation looks good.

Answer (score 1):

$(A\cup B) \setminus (A\cap B)$ is the symmetric difference (one way to say it). For your case, it is probably more readable.

You might say in notation:

$(\{x\}\cup B) \setminus (\{x\}\cap B)$

Comment: Is the Wikipedia article [Symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) helpful for you?

Answer (score 0):

While several people have mentioned the symmetric difference, perhaps its most common notation is $T=S\Delta\{x\}$. For readerships potentially unfamiliar with this, "let $T$ be the symmetric difference $S\Delta\{x\}$" is a concise way to address that.